# Absolute Value Bars Outside the Integral in a Proof

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, definite-integrals

The other day I was reading Introduction to Real Analysis by William F Trench, available free online (you can Google the title to get the pdf). I am stuck on a detail in Theorem 3.3.11:

If $f$ is integrable on $[a,b]$ and $a\le c\le b$, then $F(x)=\int_{c}^{x}f(t)dt$ is differentiable at any point $x_0$ in $(a,b)$ where $f$ is continuous , with $F'(x_0)=f(x_0)$.

In the proof, Trench considers the case where $a<x_0<b$. Since
$$f(x_0) = \frac{\int_{x_0}^{x}f(t)dt}{x-x_0},$$
Trench express the difference
$$\frac{F(x)-F(x_0)}{x-x_0} -f(x_0)$$
as an integral (marked (A))
$$\frac{\int_{x_0}^{x}(f(t)-f(x_0))dt}{x-x_0}...(A)$$
Now Trench uses Theorem 3.3.5. This theorem states that if $f$ is integrable on a closed interval $[\alpha, \beta]$ then so is $|f|$ where
$$\left|\int_{\alpha}^{\beta}f(t)dt\right| \le \int_{\alpha}^{\beta}|f(t)|dt$$

So using Theorem 3.3.5 Trench comes up with the following inequality (*)
$$\left|\frac{F(x)-F(x_0)}{x-x_0} -f(x_0)\right|\le\frac{1}{|x-x_0|}\left|\int_{x_0}^{x}|f(t)-f(x_0)|dt\right|...(*)$$

My problem with (*) is how do you justify the absolute value bars outside the integral on the RHS of the inequality.

I would be grateful for any help.
Thanks in advance!

Edit: It turns out (thanks to Bruno B.) that the reason why we need the absolute value bars is to take into account both when $x_0<x$ and when $x<x_0$. Take a look at *Elements of Real Analysis* by Charles Denlinger. Namely the proof of Theorem 7.6.8 on page 407. Here Denlinger brakes the proof up into two cases.

Comment: It doesn't hurt to do both right? If $ x < |\int f|$ then it definitely also holds $x < |\int |f| |$. Nothing was "brought out" as you can see the absolute value sign on the outside was carried over from the expression on the left, which was also outside the integral.

Comment: Bruno's answer makes a very good point!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The absolute value outside of the integral you point out is actually necessary here due to the possible "orientation" of the interval: if $x_0 > x$ then the integral would be negative!
The Theorem $3.3.5$ you mentioned (which is often called triangle inequality) works when $\alpha \leq \beta$, but you need to remember the sign changes when the inequality on the bounds is reversed. However the inequality still holds true if you make the external absolute value stay, using the fact that $|y| = |-y|$ (writing $g(t) := f(t) - f(x_0)$):
$$\left|\int_{x_0}^x g(t)\mathrm{d}t\right| = \left|\int_{x}^{x_0} g(t)\mathrm{d}t\right| \leq \int_{x}^{x_0} |g(t)|\mathrm{d}t = \left|\int_{x}^{x_0} |g(t)|\mathrm{d}t\right| = \left|\int_{x_0}^{x} |g(t)|\mathrm{d}t\right|$$

(You're probably not near that point since you're reading a real analysis book, but the same thing happens with path integrals in complex analysis, so you just need to be careful.)

Comment: Hi Bruno! That is interesting, I didn't think of that!

Comment: I initially thought that we could apply the simple fact that $y≤|y|$ for real $y$ after using Theorem 3.3.5 on (A), just having $y$ as the integral $\int_{x_0}^{x}|f(t)-f(x_0)|dt$

Comment: @Ditherer The whole point is that you can't use that theorem as long as the bounds aren't in the right order though.

Comment: Right, so we are trying to prove this inequality while taking into account both orientations (i.e. $x_0>x$ and $x<x_0$). But we only apply Theorem 3.3.5 when we have one orientation. Correct?

Comment: That is indeed correct.

Comment: @BrunoB I was thinking that maybe we could drop the bars around $x-x_0$ too along with the integral in RHS. That way, even if $x<x_0$, the RHS is still positive.

Comment: That would work I guess yeah.

Comment: It is interesting. A lot of real analysis/advanced calculus texts start off the way Trench does. Using the continuity of $f$ to get the integrand less than $\epsilon$ and have $\frac{|x-x_0|}{|x-x_0|}\cdot \epsilon$ and get the LHS of $(*)$ less than $\epsilon$. Hence the result.

Comment: As I said a lot of texts start off this way, A Friendly Introduction to Real Analysis by W. Kosmala, Introductory Real Analysis by Dangello, etc. It is a pretty standard way. I Picked Real Analysis by Trench because it was freely available online. The only problem I was having was trying to work out this bound.

Comment: Thanks Bruno B. Your answer helped me quite a bit!